# apache poi showInPane - parameter in short data type

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am making an excel file using Apache POI library.
After creating an excel file with more than 32767 rows, I can't set showInPane because of toprow parameter in short data type.
When I pass more than 32767 row as a variable, it gives me an error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: row index may not be negative
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:133)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference.<init>(CellReference.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.showInPane(XSSFSheet.java:2380)
```

Is there any way I can set the toprow overriding short data type maximum value?

**showInPane from Apache Javadoc**

```
void showInPane(short toprow, short leftcol)
    Sets desktop window pane display area, when the file is first opened in a viewer.
Parameters:
    toprow - the top row to show in desktop window pane
    leftcol - the left column to show in desktop window pane
```

http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html

Comment: Looks like a bug in POI, from the days when files didn't have so many rows. I'd suggest you raise a bug in the POI bug tracker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to a newer version of Apache POI - Dominik Stadler fixed this bug for you in [r1502749](http://svn.apache.org/r1502749)!

You'll either want a nightly build from 2013-07-14 or later, or to wait for POI 3.10 beta 2

Comment: 3.10 Beta2 didn't fix the problem. I hope this would be applied on the next version.

Comment: Sorry, it was from nightly build. https://builds.apache.org/job/POI/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/dist/

Comment: Make sure you have a nightly build from after 2013-07-14, and also make sure you're now passing in an `int` not a `short`

Comment: I was using Sheet class, not XSSFSheet class. Now it's solved with nighly build version. Thanks a lot~